# Emulating palette based graphics in WebGL v.s. Canvas 2D

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, scaling, color-palette

Currently, I'm using 2D canvas context to draw an image generated (from pixel to pixel, but refreshed as a whole buffer in once after a generated frame) from JavaScript at about a 25fps rate. The generated image is always one byte (integer / typed array) per pixel and a fixed palette is used to generate RGB final result. Scaling is also needed to adopt to the size of the canvas (ie: going to fullscreen) and/or at user request (zoom in/out buttons).

The 2D context of canvas is OK for this purpose, however I'm curious if WebGL can provide better result and/or better performance. Please note: I don't want to put pixels via webGL, I want to put pixels into my buffer (which is basically Uint8Array), and use that buffer (in once) to refresh the context. I don't know too much about WebGL, but using the needed generated image as some kind of texture would work somehow for example? Then I would need to refresh the texture at about 25fps rate, I guess.

It would be really fantastic, if WebGL support the colour space conversion somehow. With 2D context, I need to convert 1 byte / pixel buffer into RGBA for the imagedata in JavaScript for every pixel ... Scaling (for 2D context) is done now by altering the height/width style of the canvas, so browsers scales the image then. However I guess it can be slower than what WebGL can do with hw support, and also (I hope) WebGL can give greater flexibility to control the scaling, eg with the 2D context, browsers will do antialiasing even if I don't want to do (eg: integer zooming factor), and maybe that's a reason it can be quite slow sometimes.

I've already tried to learn several WebGL tutorials but all of them starts with objects, shapes, 3D cubes, etc, I don't need any - classical - object to render only what 2D context can do as well - in the hope that WebGL can be a faster solution for the very same task! Of course if there is no win here with WebGL at all, I would continue to use 2D context.

To be clear: this is some kind of computer hardware emulator done in JavaScript, and its output (what would be seen on a PAL TV connected to it) is rendered via a canvas context. The machine has fixed palette with 256 elements, internally it only needs one byte for a pixel to define its colour.

Comment: You may try some simple pallette-based format (e.g. BMP), gather as binary string, then apply base64 encoding (btoa) and update image src as data/url.

Comment: You might have a look into pixi.js. Look into the experimental branches, where they test filters, you may find something close to your neeed.

Comment: Canvas have enough performance to stream video, you dont need extra hacks.

Comment: These tutorials do not start with objects, shapes, 3d cubes, etc..
http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/

Comment: @c69 indeed, the problem that I have paletted data, with canvas you must to coversion for each pixels from JS, this is my performance problem that webGL in theory can do this, while canvas can't. Moreover: scaling up the image (scaled by integer, not so fancy stuff) can be done with a trick in js/html: to use different dimensions for css of the canvas and the actual canvas size, however it's not possible then to stop browser to do antialiasing which I don't want! So again the performance problem: I have to scale up in JS to avoid problem: quite slow. WebGL can do this too, I guess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a texture as your palette and a different texture as your image. You then get a value from the image texture and use it too look up a color from the palette texture.

The palette texture is 256x1 RGBA pixels. Your image texture is any size you want but just a single channel ALPHA texture. You can then look up a value from the image

```
    float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a * 255.0;
```

And use that value to look up a color in the palette

```
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2((index + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5));
```

Your shaders might be something like this

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = a_position;

  // assuming a unit quad for position we
  // can just use that for texcoords. Flip Y though so we get the top at 0
  v_texcoord = a_position.xy * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + 0.5;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform sampler2D u_palette;

void main() {
    float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a * 255.0;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2((index + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5));
}
```

Then you just need a palette texture.

```
 // Setup a palette.
 var palette = new Uint8Array(256 * 4);

 // I'm lazy so just setting 4 colors in palette
 function setPalette(index, r, g, b, a) {
     palette[index * 4 + 0] = r;
     palette[index * 4 + 1] = g;
     palette[index * 4 + 2] = b;
     palette[index * 4 + 3] = a;
 }
 setPalette(1, 255, 0, 0, 255); // red
 setPalette(2, 0, 255, 0, 255); // green
 setPalette(3, 0, 0, 255, 255); // blue

 // upload palette
 ...
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, 
               gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);
```

And your image. It's an alpha only image so just 1 channel.

```
 // Make image. Just going to make something 8x8
 var image = new Uint8Array([
     0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
     0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
     1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
     1,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,
     1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
     1,0,3,3,3,3,0,1,
     0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
     0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
 ]);

 // upload image
 ....
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, 8, 8, 0, gl.ALPHA, 
               gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

You also need to make sure both textures are using `gl.NEAREST` for filtering since one represents indices and the other a palette and filtering between values in those cases makes no sense.

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

// Note: createProgramFromScripts will call bindAttribLocation
// based on the index of the attibute names we pass to it.
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, 
    ["vshader", "fshader"], 
    ["a_position", "a_textureIndex"]);
gl.useProgram(program);
var imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
var paletteLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_palette");
// tell it to use texture units 0 and 1 for the image and palette
gl.uniform1i(imageLoc, 0);
gl.uniform1i(paletteLoc, 1);

// Setup a unit quad
var positions = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Setup a palette.
var palette = new Uint8Array(256 * 4);

// I'm lazy so just setting 4 colors in palette
function setPalette(index, r, g, b, a) {
    palette[index * 4 + 0] = r;
    palette[index * 4 + 1] = g;
    palette[index * 4 + 2] = b;
    palette[index * 4 + 3] = a;
}
setPalette(1, 255, 0, 0, 255); // red
setPalette(2, 0, 255, 0, 255); // green
setPalette(3, 0, 0, 255, 255); // blue

// make palette texture and upload palette
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
var paletteTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, paletteTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);

// Make image. Just going to make something 8x8
var image = new Uint8Array([
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,3,3,3,3,0,1,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
]);
    
// make image textures and upload image
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
var imageTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, 8, 8, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, positions.length / 2);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
    
      // assuming a unit quad for position we
      // can just use that for texcoords. Flip Y though so we get the top at 0
      v_texcoord = a_position.xy * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + 0.5;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform sampler2D u_palette;
    
void main() {
    float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a * 255.0;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2((index + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5));
}
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

To animate just update the image and then re-upload it into the texture

```
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, 8, 8, 0, gl.ALPHA, 
               gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

// Note: createProgramFromScripts will call bindAttribLocation
// based on the index of the attibute names we pass to it.
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, 
    ["vshader", "fshader"], 
    ["a_position", "a_textureIndex"]);
gl.useProgram(program);
var imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
var paletteLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_palette");
// tell it to use texture units 0 and 1 for the image and palette
gl.uniform1i(imageLoc, 0);
gl.uniform1i(paletteLoc, 1);

// Setup a unit quad
var positions = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Setup a palette.
var palette = new Uint8Array(256 * 4);

// I'm lazy so just setting 4 colors in palette
function setPalette(index, r, g, b, a) {
    palette[index * 4 + 0] = r;
    palette[index * 4 + 1] = g;
    palette[index * 4 + 2] = b;
    palette[index * 4 + 3] = a;
}
setPalette(1, 255, 0, 0, 255); // red
setPalette(2, 0, 255, 0, 255); // green
setPalette(3, 0, 0, 255, 255); // blue

// make palette texture and upload palette
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
var paletteTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, paletteTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);

// Make image. Just going to make something 8x8
var width = 8;
var height = 8;
var image = new Uint8Array([
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,3,3,3,3,0,1,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
]);
    
// make image textures and upload image
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
var imageTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, width, height, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    
var frameCounter = 0;
function render() {  
  ++frameCounter;
    
  // skip 3 of 4 frames so the animation is not too fast
  if ((frameCounter & 3) == 0) {
    // rotate the image left
    for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      var temp = image[y * width];
      for (var x = 0; x < width - 1; ++x) {
        image[y * width + x] = image[y * width + x + 1];
      }
      image[y * width + width - 1] = temp;
    }
    // re-upload image
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, width, height, 0, gl.ALPHA,
                  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, positions.length / 2);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
    
      // assuming a unit quad for position we
      // can just use that for texcoords. Flip Y though so we get the top at 0
      v_texcoord = a_position.xy * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + 0.5;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform sampler2D u_palette;
    
void main() {
    float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a * 255.0;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2((index + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5));
}
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Of course that assumes your goal is to do the animation on the CPU by manipulating pixels. Otherwise you can use any normal webgl techniques to manipulate texture coordinates or whatever.

You can also update the palette similarly for palette animation. Just modify the palette and re-upload it

```
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, 
               gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);
```

Example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

// Note: createProgramFromScripts will call bindAttribLocation
// based on the index of the attibute names we pass to it.
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, 
    ["vshader", "fshader"], 
    ["a_position", "a_textureIndex"]);
gl.useProgram(program);
var imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
var paletteLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_palette");
// tell it to use texture units 0 and 1 for the image and palette
gl.uniform1i(imageLoc, 0);
gl.uniform1i(paletteLoc, 1);

// Setup a unit quad
var positions = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Setup a palette.
var palette = new Uint8Array(256 * 4);

// I'm lazy so just setting 4 colors in palette
function setPalette(index, r, g, b, a) {
    palette[index * 4 + 0] = r;
    palette[index * 4 + 1] = g;
    palette[index * 4 + 2] = b;
    palette[index * 4 + 3] = a;
}
setPalette(1, 255, 0, 0, 255); // red
setPalette(2, 0, 255, 0, 255); // green
setPalette(3, 0, 0, 255, 255); // blue

// make palette texture and upload palette
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
var paletteTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, paletteTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);

// Make image. Just going to make something 8x8
var width = 8;
var height = 8;
var image = new Uint8Array([
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,3,3,3,3,0,1,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
]);
    
// make image textures and upload image
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
var imageTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, width, height, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    
var frameCounter = 0;
function render() {  
  ++frameCounter;
    
  // skip 3 of 4 frames so the animation is not too fast
  if ((frameCounter & 3) == 0) {
    // rotate the 3 palette colors
    var tempR = palette[4 + 0];
    var tempG = palette[4 + 1];
    var tempB = palette[4 + 2];
    var tempA = palette[4 + 3];
    setPalette(1, palette[2 * 4 + 0], palette[2 * 4 + 1], palette[2 * 4 + 2], palette[2 * 4 + 3]);
    setPalette(2, palette[3 * 4 + 0], palette[3 * 4 + 1], palette[3 * 4 + 2], palette[3 * 4 + 3]);
    setPalette(3, tempR, tempG, tempB, tempA);

    // re-upload palette
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
                  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, palette);
    
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, positions.length / 2);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
    
      // assuming a unit quad for position we
      // can just use that for texcoords. Flip Y though so we get the top at 0
      v_texcoord = a_position.xy * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + 0.5;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform sampler2D u_palette;
    
void main() {
    float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a * 255.0;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2((index + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5));
}
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Slightly related is this tile shader example
http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/07/sprite-tile-maps-on-gpu.html

Comment: Also, to add up , can the logic of canvas which is <br/>`imgData[idx++] = window.colorBufView[position+2]; // red
    imgData[idx++] = window.colorBufView[position+1]; // green
    imgData[idx++] = window.colorBufView[position]; // blue
    imgData[idx++] = 255; // alpha` can be written in fragment shader (see below comment)

Comment: 'void main(void) {','float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a;',
                                             'gl_FragColor.r = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index         , 0.5)).r;',
                                             'gl_FragColor.g = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index + 0.001 , 0.5)).g;',
                                             'gl_FragColor.b = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index + 0.002, 0.5)).b;',
                                             'gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;',
                                             
                                            '}'

Comment: In the original examples u_palette is already pointing to a RGBA texture so one texture2D command pulls out RGBA. No need to pull them out separately. also your 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 as a texcoord does nothing. On clamp or repeat those are the same coordinate since texture coords only go from 0.0 to 1.0. PS: I updated the fragment shaders above. [See this post as to why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27439675/128511). Other ideas, you need to make sure all your textures are using gl.NEAREST for filtering since they are indices into palettes and filting would break that.

Comment: okay after tweaking the color table a bit I got the expected result. Thanks.  But if I keep the value as 0.0 for the second argument it renders the image correctly , changing it changes the color .`'gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index, 0.0));',`

Comment: Congratulations!  Yes, that 2nd value can be anything if the texture is 1 line tall. It's just arguably more correct to sample the center of texels than the edges. See the post linked to where that was the case in the first value (not the second)

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you're building up a javascript array that's around 512 x 512 (PAL size)...

A WebGL fragment shader could definitely do your palette conversion pretty nicely. The recipe would go something like this:

1. Set up WebGL with a "geometry" of just two triangles that span your viewport. (GL is all triangles.) This is the biggest bother, if you're not already GL fluent. But it's not that bad. Spend some quality time with http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217 . But it will be ~100 lines of stuff. Price of admission.
2. Build your in-memory frame buffer 4 times bigger. (I think textures always have to be RGBA?) And populate every fourth byte, the R component, with your pixel values. Use new Float32Array to allocate it. You can use values 0-255, or divide it down to 0.0 to 1.0. We'll pass this to webgl as a texture. This one changes every frame.
3. Build a second texture that's 256 x 1 pixels, which is your palette lookup table. This one never changes (unless the palette can be modified?).
4. In your fragment shader, use your emulated frame buffer texture as a lookup into your palette. The first pixel in the palette is accessed at location (0.5/256.0, 0.5), middle of the pixel.
5. On each frame, resubmit the emulated frame buffer texture and redraw. Pushing pixels to the GPU is expensive... but a PAL-sized image is pretty small by modern standards.
6. Bonus step: You could enhance the fragment shader to imitate scanlines, interlace video, or other cute emulation artifacts (phosphor dots?) on modern high-resolution displays, all at no cost to your javascript!

This is just a sketch. But it will work. WebGL is a pretty low-level API, and quite flexible, but well worth the effort (if you like that kind of thing, which I do. :-) ).

Again, http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217 is well-recommended for overall WebGL guidance.

Comment: "2.Build your in-memory frame buffer 4 times bigger." Actually, the fragment shader could index through the 4 color components r,g,b,&a so you could pack your texture tighter... but I'd go with basic for the first pass. :)

Comment: You can make one channel textures. `gl.ALPHA` or `gl.LUMINANCE`. As for lookup in the 256x1 texture, if you have texture filtering set to `gl.NEAREST` then you should just be able to look up directly with something like.
`float index = texture2D(u_pixels, v_texcoord).r; gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index, 0.5));`