# how to pick pixel value from a specific index of a texture in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I am rendering a texture where I am stuck at a point where I need to pick values from some specific index to update the current index.

For EG :

```
float someColor = texture2D(u_image, vTexCoord).r; //assume u_image is 10*10 image
if (someColor.r > 0.5) {
    someColor = someColorPalette[(zr*zcols)+(zc-1)]; //someColorPalette is another texture
//where (zr*zcols)+(zc-1) is getting the pixel value from some index using the calculation 
}
```

`

In the above snippet I know that `someColorPalette[(zr*zcols)+(zc-1)]` is a CPU statement and won't work in opengl.
Can anyone suggest for some alternate solution to read from index of a texture?

Comment: looking at your variable names you might [find this useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719654/128511)

Comment: The answer will depend on which OpenGL version you're talking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For GLSL ES 1.0 to pull out a specific texel from a texture use

```
 vec2 resolutionOfTexture = vec2(someWidth, someHeight)
 int pixelX = ?
 int pixelY = ?

 vec2 uv = (vec2(pixelX, pixelY) + .5) / resolutionOfTexture;
 vec4 color = texture(someTexture, uv);
```

You need to add .5 to target the center of texels, otherwise you're targeting edges and you might get the wrong pixel.

Of course `resolutionOfTexture` and `pixelX` and `pixelY` can all be uniforms or whatever

For GLSL ES 3.0 use

```
 vec4 color = texelFetch(someTexture, ivec2(pixelX, pixelY), 0);
```

If you want a linear index then in GLSL ES 1.0

```
 pixelX = mod(someIndex, resolutionOfTexture.x);
 pixelY = floor(someIndex / resolutionOfTexture.x);
```

in GLSL ES 3.0

```
 ivec2 texSize = textureSize(someTexture, 0);
 pixelX = someIndex % texSize.x;
 pixelY = someIndex / texSize.x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions , let me try them one by one. I am still using WebGl1 so I think first answer will do for me.