# How to use packed pixel array in WebGL Texture?

Tags: webgl, texture2d

I'm new to WebGL. I'm using pixel array in texture2D API.
It works fine when I have unpacked pixel array ( size = width * height * 4).

Is it possible to have packed pixel array (size as width * height) and unpack the color in texture API?

Comment: What do you mean "packed pixel array*. Do you mean indexed texture / paletted graphics like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695658/emulating-palette-based-graphics-in-webgl-v-s-canvas-2d

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I would like to have only one channel texture and look up the color in the texture. Do you have any example?

Comment: Did you read the answers in the linked question? They have examples