# 2D Color Grid in GLSL Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to achieve this pattern in GLSL:
[image]

While getting that effect on the X axis is straightforward by scaling, using `floor()` and `mix()`:

```
void main() {
  vec2 st = vTexCoord;

  float maxColumns = 100.0;
  float columns = floor(mouse.x * maxColumns);

  // scale the coordinate system to the columns
  st = st * (columns + 1.0);

  float x = floor(st.x) / columns;
  vec3 color = mix(colorA, colorB, min(1.0, x));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

However, achieving rows is not so simple. I tried using the following approach with arrays of colors and dynamic indices:

```
void main() {
  vec2 st = vTexCoord;

  float maxColumns = 100.0;
  float columns = floor(mouse.x * maxColumns);
  st = st * (columns + 1.0);

  float x = floor(st.x) / columns;

  float maxRows = 2.0;
  float row = mouse.y * maxRows;
  int y = int(floor(row));

  vec3 color = mix(colorsA[y], colorsB[y], min(1.0, x));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

After seeing this error, it looks like I'm taking the wrong approach:

```
Darn! An error occurred compiling the fragment shader:ERROR: 0:46: '[]' : Index expression must be constant
ERROR: 0:46: '[]' : Index expression must be constant
```

What would be a correct approach to a 2D color grid in a GLSL fragment shader?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, is this it? 
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3lXfWS

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious question would be, why are you not just using a texture for the entire thing instead of a shader? Texture are a million times more flexible.

In any case you didn't define `colorA` and `colorB` but as the error says, in WebGL1, indices must be constant expressions.

If you want to look up values from an array put those values in a texture. Textures are basically arrays.

```
uniform sampler2D colorA;
uniform sampler2D colorB;
uniform vec2 colorADimensions;
uniform vec2 colorBDimensions;
...

   vec3 cA = texture2D(colorA, (vec2(column, row) + 0.5)  colorADimensions).rgb;
   vec3 cB = texture2D(colorB, (vec2(column, row) + 0.5)  colorBDimensions).rgb;
   vec3 color = mix(cA, cB, min(1.0, x));
```

This is semi-related: [using a texture to emulate indexed palette graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719654/128511)

otherwise something like this will generate something similar to your image

```
void main() {
  vec3 colorsA = vec3(1,0,0);
  vec3 colorsB = vec3(0,1,1);
  vec3 colorsC = vec3(0,0,0);
  vec3 colorsD = vec3(1,1,0);
  vec2 vTexCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;

  // -----------

  vec2 st = vTexCoord;

  vec2 maxColRows = vec2(100, 2);
  vec2 colRows = floor(mouse * maxColRows);

  st = st * (colRows + 1.0);

  vec2 xy = floor(st) / colRows;

  vec3 colorTop = mix(colorsA, colorsB, min(1.0, xy.x));
  vec3 colorBottom = mix(colorsC, colorsD, min(1.0, xy.x));

  vec3 color = mix(colorTop, colorBottom, min(1.0, xy.y));;
    
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

http://glslsandbox.com/e#66911.0